# Usage of "even if"

Tags: word-usage, commas, conditionals

Could you please suggest me the usage of  "even if" in the English sentence? 
For example, is the following statement correct grammatically?

> Even if this approach scale for a large number of  similar nodes, it is impractical for large scale heterogeneous system.

Please correct my punctuation errors also. In my opinion, the above sentence should be written the following way.

> Even if**,** this approach scale for a large number of  similar nodes, it is impractical for large scale heterogeneous system.

Comment: Are you asking *only* about punctuation or do you have some doubts about a sentence should be structured if it involves "even if"?

Comment: This seems like proofreading, which is off-topic.  If it's not, then it's not clear exactly what your question is.

Comment: I'm closevoting as Off Topic (proofreading), because both the sentences contain multiple basic errors that would inevitably have to be addressed by any "reasonable" answer.

Comment: Both are incorrect. As has been pointed out, there is no comma intonation after _even if_, just as there is none after _if_. **And** it should be _this approach scales_, because the verb in the clause is in third person singular present form, and that takes _-s_.

Comment: @JohnLawler Long ago and far away, this was perfectly legal: it brooked no *-s*.  However, **even if it *be*** a legal form in the mouths of our ancestors, the ***present subjunctive*** just doesn’t get used in *even if* clauses in the 21st century (outside of the rare legal document).

Comment: Right. Because there is no present subjunctive in English to be used. If this be an idiom, make the most of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one is closer to being correct than the second one. Here is the correct version, assuming I'm interpreting the meaning correctly:

Even if this approach scale**s** for a large number of similar nodes, it is impractical for **a** heterogeneous system.

There were a couple errors in your first sentence:

1. The first use of the word *scale* should be plural, since the object which is performing the action is singular. If the sentence read "these approaches[...]" rather than "this approach [...]", *scale* would have been correct.
2. You missed the letter *a* before "heterogenous system". You probably just accidentally left it out, but just in case you didn't, the word *a* is placed before a singular noun, usually when referring to a general, arbitrary example of something.

Now, on to your actual question -- "Even if" shouldn't be separated from the rest of the clause with a comma. A comma *typically* implies the end of a clause. "Even if", in this case, is a *qualifier* for the rest of the clause ("this approach scales well for a large number of similar nodes"), which means that it gives additional meaning to the clause. Because of that, it should not be separated.

This was a bit of a tricky question to answer. It's really just one of those phrases that you have to just hear a few times and let it become natural.

Answer (score 2):

You don’t want the comma after “Even if”, and the sentence has a couple of other minor errors. Try something like the following:

> Even if this approach scales for a large number of similar nodes, it is impractical for a large scale, heterogeneous system.

Comment: I appreciate that you're correcting the entire sentence, as opposed to answering only the question as stated by the OP, but leoger's answer is a valid and correct answer to the question as stated, so it would be better to spell that out instead of just saying "leoger is wrong".  (Also, the +1 comment should really be a comment or an upvote when you get the rep, not a part of your own answer.)  Thanks for answering, though, and welcome to the site!

Comment: Cheers Hellion. I'll take your points on board. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first usage is correct. It sounds natural and the punctuation is in correct places.

The second sentence does not use the comma placement correctly.

Comment: This is incorrect. There are two punctuation errors in the first sentence. In addition, this answer would have been insufficient even if it had been correct, since you didn't provide any additional information or insight.